# Determine whether the request is coming from mobile app

Tags: angular, laravel, ionic-framework

I've developed a mobile app(ionic, angular) and a web app(Laravel).
When I click on the (Feedback) button on mobile app then it will open the mobile browser and will be navigated to webapp/feedback page. `InAppBrowser` is used for that.

From web app, I need to identify whether the request came from the mobile app.
Because that link should not be able to opened directly.
Is there any specific way to do this?

Comment: you can pass query param in your url to get device. something like: `example.com/device=mobile` for mobile and for normal web: `example.com/device=desktop` something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Cordova InAppBrowser directly or with the Ionic wrapper and use the target of _self. It should open in the webview.

E.g

```js
cordova.InAppBrowser.create('https://somewebsite.com/', '_self', 'usewkwebview=yes')
```

Edit:
If you want to accept only your mobile app, you need to create middleware

E.g

```
php artisan make:middleware EnsureIsMobileApp
```

IN EnsureIsMobileApp middleware

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->input('token') !== 'Jjfi393ij9w') { //random secret code
            abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
        }
        unset($request['token']); //if you want to remove token
        return $next($request);
    }
```

Call form your app

```
https://somewebsite.com/?token=Jjfi393ij9w
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to identify whether the request is coming from app?

Comment: Do you need to call securely? Accept only your app call?

Comment: Thanks, this will solve my problem. But is there any way to remove token parameter from from `$request` before `return $next($request);`

Comment: Try with this code ` unset($request['token']);`